# Need to set Default Document and Physical path in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am not able to see my SPA page after deploying it to Azure WebApp from VS Code. Its says

"Hey, Node developers!

Your app service is up and running.
Time to take the next step and deploy your code."

I have seen at so may site that I need to set default document and New physical path. But i don't see any Default Document Tab in Configuration menu of Web App. There are only three tabs. 1- Application Setting 2- General Setting 3- Path Mapping.
The Issue is where to set the Default document and new physical path.

Comment: Seems Default Document Tab is not available with Pay as You go or some particular  Pricing Tier. Not sure if my understanding is correct or not. But on which pricing tier it will be available, that is also not known.

Comment: Could you set the default document with my way?

Comment: Default Document Tab is not available in Linux Web Apps

Answer (score 3):

If you deployed to a Node Linux Web App the default document would be hostingstart.html located in /home/site/wwwroot/.

According this document:[Things You Should Know: Web Apps and Linux](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/), there is a description about [default document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/#NodeHome) in a Node.js app.

> When you create a Node.js app, by default, it's going to use hostingstart.html as the default document unless you configure it to look for a different file. You can use a JavaScript file to configure your default document. Create a file called index.js in the root folder of your site and add the following content.

So go to your ssh terminal, navigate to `/home/site/wwwroot` , create the index.js with the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var options = {
index: 'index.html'
};
server.use('/', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options));
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: Thanks George.For now, i have deployed it in storage account static website.